# How to click on a button with a class and an ID given for the particular button

Tags: vba, web-scraping

Snip of HTML:

[image: HTML]

```
For Each element In HTMLdoc1.getElementsByClassName("dashboard_popup_button")
If InStr(element.innerText, "Time and Expense Download") > 0 Then element.Click: Exit For
```

Next element

Comment: Share the site ink.

Comment: Actually cannot as it is an internal site. I am afraid i do not have the required permission.

Comment: If you wanna click on that specific button containing this text `Time and Expense Download`, you don't need any loop to find that. Try using that id directly within `.getElementById()`.

Comment: @SIM actually i did try that at first but it does not help, it does not get clicked. Actually there is a click on an option after which a pop up with 5 options appear out of which this one has to be clicked, all remaining 4 options have same class but different IDs and that is helpful but does not work.

Comment: Did you add some delay before clicking on that button? You may also check whether the button is within an iframe or kendo-grid. Given that these all are hypothetical suggestions. Thanks.